# Calculating average from array and recieving a NaN error

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm having issues with trying to convert objects from a string array into integers. I've used parseInt and parseFloat but none of it is working. Do I need to maybe structure the array declaration differently or the prompt?

Thanks guys

```js
var scores = [];

  document.writeln("<font face='arial' size=''><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>")
  
  for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
   scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + i);
   document.writeln("<tr><td style='padding: 5px;'><b>Score " + i + "</b></td>");
   document.writeln("<td style='padding: 5px;' contenteditable='true'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");
   document.writeln("</tr>");
  }

  function Average(){
     var sum = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(sum + scores[i]);
   }
   var avg = sum/scores.length;
   document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("Your score average is: " + avg);
  }
```

Comment: sum += parseInt(scores[i]); could help - number plus string create string and sum was there twice.

Comment: The first element in an array is at index `0`. The loop in `Average()` is correct but not the first one.

Comment: @Tom Tried it, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
    var scores = [];

    document.writeln("<font face='arial' size=''><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>")

    for(var i=0; i<=9; i++){
        scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + (i+1));
        document.writeln("<tr><td style='padding: 5px;'><b>Score " + (i + 1) + "</b></td>");
        document.writeln("<td style='padding: 5px;' contenteditable='true'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }

    function Average(){
        var sum = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
            sum += parseInt(scores[i], 10);
        }

        var avg = sum/scores.length;
        document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("Your score average is: " + avg);
    }
```

Thanks for the help, Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the for loop for prompt from 1 to 10, but calculating the sum in `Average` looping 0 to 9. The scores[0] is `undefined` as it is never assigned a value in the prompt loop whcih results to `NaN` when added to other numbers. Also you're adding sum in `parseInt` which is wrong.

Here is the fixed code :

```
   var scores = [];

    document.writeln("<font face='arial' size=''><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>")

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + (i+1));
        document.writeln("<tr><td style='padding: 5px;'><b>Score " + i + "</b></td>");
        document.writeln("<td style='padding: 5px;' contenteditable='true'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }

    function Average(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
            sum += parseInt(scores[i]);
        }
        var avg = sum/scores.length;
        document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("Your score average is: " + avg);
    }
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

following line is wrong in your code :

```
scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + i);
```

I have written a small piece of javascript code which will do the average calculation. What it's doing is, getting the number in a variable from the prompt and pushing it into the array.

```js
function calAverage(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    var avg = sum/scores.length;
    return avg;
}

var scores = [];
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++){
    var number = prompt("Enter score :");
    scores.push(parseInt(number));
}

console.log(scores);

var average = calAverage(scores);

console.log("Average = " + average);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. `scores[i] = prompt("Enter score " + i);`, I would exchange this for `scores.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter score " + i)));`, as `prompt` returns a string, upon which most operations will fail and return NaN. Setting `scores[i] =` does work, but can be messy if you try to scale it up.
2. `sum += parseInt(sum + scores[i]);`, you have already got the `+=`, and as such the extra `sum + ...` effectively translates to `sum = (2 * sum) + scores[i]`, meaning we can reduce this to `sum += scores[i];`

The complete code:

```
var scores = [];

document.writeln("<font face='arial' size=''><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>")

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
    scores.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter score " + i)));
    document.writeln("<tr><td style='padding: 5px;'><b>Score " + i + "</b></td>");
    document.writeln("<td style='padding: 5px;' contenteditable='true'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");
    document.writeln("</tr>");
}

function Average(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
        sum += scores[i];
    }
    var avg = sum/scores.length;
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("Your score average is: " + avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification in your code and also applied a check if user enter any value other than a number.

```js
var scores = [];

    document.writeln("<font face='arial' size=''><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>")

    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
        scores[i] = parseFloat(prompt("Enter score " + (i+1)));
        if(isNaN(scores[i])){
          scores[i]=0;
        }
        document.writeln("<tr><td style='padding: 5px;'><b>Score " + i + "</b></td>");
        document.writeln("<td style='padding: 5px;' contenteditable='true'><center>" + scores[i] + "</center></td>");
        document.writeln("</tr>");
    }
    
    Average();
    
    function Average(){
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
            sum += parseInt(scores[i]);
        }
        var avg = sum/scores.length;
       document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = ("Your score average is: " + avg);
        
    }
```

```html
<div id="average"></div>
```